# Windows Form Culture not setting up

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get right string values from culture resource file but it's not working, always returning english resources,

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); 

but 

Resources.Resource1.myResource;
```

still getting english resources, I have two files   `Resource1.resx and Resource1.fr-FR.resx`

Comment: solved problem by using Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("myResource", cul);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
```

[Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets the current culture used by the Resource Manager to look
>   up culture-specific resources at run time.

Comment: it worked on development server but when i took file to integration server, it didn't worked, what could be the issue, do i need to embed resources to exe too.